# Import .csv and convert custom datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

I need to import a csv file and convert data in the first column to proper datetime format. Currently, the sample data looks like:

```
Date, ID, Size
2000-10-10X12:10:5, HKA2, 10
2000-10-12X10:10:5, HKA2, 10
```

When imported with `pandas.read_csv()`, the first column is always being converted to a number instead of string!

My question is:

1. Why does pandas automatically convert the first column to a number with a wrong value?
2. How do fix it?

   ```
   Date, ID, Size
   2000-10-10 12:10:5, HKA2, 10
   2000-10-12 10:10:5, HKA2, 10
   ```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you mean by removing the `X` and make it to be `datetime`.

Try this oneliner:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str.replace('X', ' '))
```

`df` becomes:

```
                 Date     ID   Size
0 2000-10-10 12:10:05   HKA2     10
1 2000-10-12 10:10:05   HKA2     10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I was not able to import the first column as a string in the first place. It always convert the datetime string to weird/wrong numeric values...

Comment: @CryptTP Hope it works :), please remember to accept if it does haha

Answer (score 0):

```
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "filename.csv",
        parse_dates=['report_date', 'updated_at'],
        infer_datetime_format=True
    )
    df['report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['report_date'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
    df['updated_at']  = pd.to_datetime(df['updated_at'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

**formatstr, default None**
The strftime to parse time, eg “%d/%m/%Y”, note that “%f” will parse all the way up to nanoseconds. See strftime documentation for more information on choices: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Comment: Your answer would work if I could have imported the Date column as string. Unfortunately, it was converted into numeric values and I don't know why. Can you specify the type for the Date column alone?

Comment: While reading the csv, we passed dictionary with dtype key. Inside this dictionary we mention to type for each column to read by pandas. Inside this types, I don't mention the type of report_date either date or datetime. I'm not passing any time for the date column therefor, it takes the value in the same format as in the source table and then explicitly convert to datetime by using pd.to_datetime function. So the trick is not to specify the type while reading csv but convert it after reading csv . I'm currently using the same technique in my current project

Comment: Would be glad if you accept this answer / upvote. Thanks